# Namespace web not found

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sendgrid

I am following through the tutorial by Microsoft to integrate with SendGrid. Their code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset).

Now I am using .Net framework 4.5.2 and I am getting an error on the line:

```
  // Create a Web transport for sending email.
  var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
```

The error says "The type or namespace name 'Web' could not be found."
I have searched online and couldn't find much about it. I have got all the namespaces that they have mentioned in the page.

Anyone can give me some clues please?

Thanks.
Behdad.

Comment: Does your project have a reference to the SendGrid assembly?

Comment: you may add via "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/" as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for anyone else getting stuck trying to configure their MVC 5 project to all sending confirmation emails here is the information:

1. I was following through [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)
2. The problem I was facing was I couldn't see the namespace Web
3. So after you create a SendGrid account on Azure use the username/password on Sendgrid.com and get an API key
4. Then using that API key, use the following code to send your emails:

   ```
   private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
   {
       var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY"];
       var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
       var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
       var subject = message.Subject;
       var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
       var plainTextContent = message.Body;
       var htmlContent = message.Body;
       var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

       await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
   }
   ```

The above code was copied from [here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d53afeb-95e0-490e-8db8-74dddf43c831/the-type-or-namespace-name-web-could-not-be-found?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Just to add here is a document which I edited to add .NET Core API example with MVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Comment: The document which you are following is not up to date with V3 API.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Not familiar with this part of MVC and this helped me a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the `SendGrid` package to your project. Then, add `using SendGrid;` to your class.

If you have already, you may click on `Web` and press `Alt + Shift + F10` to see options available.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes I already had it installed and was including SendGrid. Stil the word Web is in red and can't see any options.

Comment: Type in SendGrid. in the class. If intellisense shows Web class, you are good. If not, there is something missing.

Comment: Thanks danish. Yes, I couldn't see the Web. But just posted the below response.